# Tool to extract information from Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

I have multiple calendars in Google Calendar, for various categories of work, of personal stuff, etc.

I would like a tool (possibly a bunch of scripts) that would grab the information and summarise it, e.g. via weekly totals of time spent on each.

Ideally, that tool would be able to do things like "categorize all agenda items that start with PREP as 'Preparation time', and count the total amount of prep. time this week."

Does that tool exist, or am I going to code my own thing?

Many thanks in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this is simple but efficient enough:

https://google-calendar-hours.com/

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer, as an aid to others who read this question in future